# when i dynamically Add Views into View,this kind of phenomenon appeared

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-layout-weight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJbjL.jpg) 
   When i add view to a LinearLayout dynamically, it appeared ..

```
Here is the picture , In the views at the bottom of the display is not complete ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzJT7.png)  In hear as the picture show .

The NoticeTextViewGroup extends LinearLayout，setNoticeGroup is the addview method...

```
    public void setNoticeGroup(List<String> notices) {
        noticeGroup.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < notices.size(); i++) {
            NoticeTextView not = new NoticeTextView(getContext());
            not.setItemTextColor(mTextColor);
            not.setItemTNumColor(mNumColor);
            String symbol = mItemStyle == None ? " " : mItemStyle == Dot ? getResources().getString(R.string.symbol_Dot) + " " : (i + 1) + ".";
            not.setString(symbol);
            not.setText(notices.get(i));
            noticeGroup.addView(not);
        }
        noticeGroup.requestLayout();
    }
```

And the NoticeTextView also  extends LinearLayout,

```
private void initView() {
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_notice_text, this);
        mNum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_num);
        text_root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.text_root);
        mContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);
    }
public void setText(String str) {
        mContent.setText(str);
    }
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with the layout params of the views you are adding, can you post that code ?

Comment: In NoticeTextViewGroup , i not override onMeasure() method . It is the reason cause the problem? And how to add layout params ?  Thank you...

Comment: you are utilizing entire screen, have you tried putting entire layout inside scrollview?

Comment: yes,and i tried scrollview.requestLayout(), but it did't worked neither.